# Contador no funciona como debería

Tags: javascript, fetch

Tengo este [código(GitHub)](https://github.com/salvamn/04-Ejemplo-api-superhero) que en resumen lo que hace es mostrar imágenes de superhéroes o villanos y comparar sus estadísticas, y el que tenga mejores estadísticas se le suma un punto.

El problema es que el contador que lleva la puntuación no esta actualizándose correctamente, por ejemplo: cuando doy clic se muestran las dos imágenes de superhéroes pero no actualiza el contador, pero si le doy clic al botón nuevamente el contador si se actualiza.

El marcador se debe actualizar al presionar el botón y no cuando se presione nuevamente el botón.

[Pagina](https://salvamn.github.io/04-Ejemplo-api-superhero/)

```
boton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  pintarHeroeOVillano(contenedor_resultado)
  pintarHeroeOVillano2(contenedor_resultado2)

  compararEstadisticas(estadisticasU1, estadisticasU2)

  estadisticasU2 = []
  estadisticasU1 = []
})




function compararEstadisticas(listaU1, listaU2){
  if(listaU1[0] > listaU2[0]){
    console.log("Usuario 1 gana")

    contadorUsuario1++
    document.getElementById('usuario1').innerHTML = contadorUsuario1

    console.log(estadisticasU1)
    console.log(estadisticasU2)

 }else if(listaU1[0] < listaU2[0]){
    console.log("Usuario 2 gana")

    contadorUsuario2++
    document.getElementById('usuario2').innerHTML = contadorUsuario2

    console.log(estadisticasU1)
    console.log(estadisticasU2)

 }else if(listaU1[0] === listaU2[0]){
    console.log("Empate")

    console.log(estadisticasU1)
    console.log(estadisticasU2)
    }
}

function pintarHeroeOVillano(caja){
caja.innerHTML = ''
// const rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 731)
const rndInt = parseInt(Math.random() * (563 - 0) + 1) // 731
// console.log(rndInt)

fetch(jotason)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    // console.log(data)
    caja.innerHTML += `
    <div class='tarjeta'>

        <img width='220px' src='${data[rndInt].images.md}'></img>
        <h1><u>${data[rndInt].name}</u></h1>
        <h2>
            Bando: ${data[rndInt].biography.alignment === 'good' ? 'Bueno' : 'Malo'} - ${data[rndInt].biography.publisher}
        </h2>
        <h3>Estadisticas de poder</h3>

        <span style="color: ${parseInt(data[rndInt].powerstats.intelligence) >= 70 ? 'green' : 'red'};">
            Inteligencia: ${data[rndInt].powerstats.intelligence}
        </span>

        <span style="color: ${parseInt(data[rndInt].powerstats.strength) >= 70 ? 'green' : 'red'};">
            Fuerza: ${data[rndInt].powerstats.strength}
        </span>

        <span style="color: ${parseInt(data[rndInt].powerstats.speed) >= 60 ? 'green' : 'red'};">
            Velocidad: ${data[rndInt].powerstats.speed}   
        </span>

        <span style="color: ${parseInt(data[rndInt].powerstats.durability) >= 50 ? 'green' : 'red'};">
            Durabilidad: ${data[rndInt].powerstats.durability}
        </span>

        <span style="color: ${parseInt(data[rndInt].powerstats.power) >= 70 ? 'green' : 'red'};">
            Poder: ${data[rndInt].powerstats.power}
        </span>

        <span style="color: ${parseInt(data[rndInt].powerstats.combat) >= 65 ? 'green' : 'red'};">
            Combate: ${data[rndInt].powerstats.combat}
        </span>

    </tarjeta>
    `

    estadisticasU1 = [
        data[rndInt].powerstats.intelligence,
        data[rndInt].powerstats.speed,
        data[rndInt].powerstats.durability,
        data[rndInt].powerstats.power,
        data[rndInt].powerstats.combat,
        data[rndInt].powerstats.strength
    ]

})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
}
```

Comment: De seguro estas teniendo un problema con la asincronia. Creo que deberias usar async/await en las funciones pintarheroeovillano() porq de seguro la funcion de estadisticas se ejecuta antes que pintar....

Comment: @HernánGarcia Efectivamente, estaba verificando con la consola que es lo primero que se ejecuta al presionar el botón y era la función de estadísticas y luego se ejecutaban las otras.